# MATLAB issue For

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Calculate the periodogram, using the variables `a` and `b`, for a sequence of frequencies `f`, between 1 and 20, with intervals of 0.2. For each frequency value, find the values, through the equation

```
T = (1/(4*pi*f))*atan(sum(sin(4*pi*f*t(i))))/(sum(cos(4*pi*f*t(i)))
```

Then, calculate the value of the periodgram for the frequency `f`, `P(f)`, through the equation:

```
P(f) = ((sum(MasterYi(i)*sin(2*pi*f(t(i)-T))))^2)/(sum(sin^2(2*pi*f(t(i)-T))))+... ((sum(MasterYi(i)*cos(2*pi*f(t(i)-T))))^2)/(sum(cos^2(2*pi*f(t(i)-T))))
```

Where,

```
MasterYi = a * sin(2*pi*f(ti-T))+b*cos(2*pi*f(ti-T))
```

I have this code:

```
for f = 1:0.2:20
%t is a value that we know
t = 1:82;
T(:,f) = (1./(4*pi.*f)).*tan(sum(sin(4*pi*f*t(:,f))))./(sum(cos(4*pi*f.*t(:,f))))

end
```

At the moment we are just trying to get the values for `T`, but it says:

> index must be real positive integers or logicals.

Comment: Yes, obvious error. You are not calling real positive integers or logicals as an index, but `t(:,f)`. How'd you define a matrix entry at M(3,4.2)? Rather weird. What is the purpose of `t(:,f)`? `t` is a row vector, thus calling all rows is pretty redundant. `f` contains 95 values, whilst `t` has 82 values. You thus can't simply substitute `f` for its index number.

Comment: Start with a single value for `f` and make sure you're getting the right answer.  I'm not sure `T` is even correct for a single value...let alone the total loop.  This is before even trying to loop.  Some problems with `tan(sum(....) ./ sum(....)`...no need for the dot operator for 2 single values.  And the `t(:,f)` really makes no sense there.

Comment: I've eddited the question, to be as clear as possible.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not used to use the stackoverflow and I'm tilting a lot with this exercise. Thank you for trying to help. I don't know what to write on the code besides that...

Answer (score 0):

I am very confused as to what's going on.  I am making the assumption that the `t(:,f)` in the question is an error.  Using that assumption one way to solve the problem of the `T` value is as follows:

```
% create a function handle to the T equation
T = @(f,t) (1/(4*pi*f))*atan(sum(sin(4*pi*f*t)))/(sum(cos(4*pi*f*t)));
% create the t vector
t = 0:82;
% create the f vector
f = 1:.02:20;
% pre-allocate the results Tresults
Tresults = zeros(length(f),1);
% loop over f finding T
for x = 1:length(f)
    Tresults(x) = T(f(x), t);
end
```

The problem is you need to use an integer as an index for your results.  `f` cannot be the index because it contains values like `1.2, 1.4, 1.6` which are not integers.  You can follow this pattern and extend it to the rest of your equations.  I would continue but there are variables missing like `ti, a, b` in the problem description.  There are cool ways to solve this using `bsxfun` but that is too advanced at this stage.